How to expedite data retrieval and transformation via API and utilize them in Airflow?
I'm working on a project where I need to retrieve weather forecast data from the Yandex Weather API for multiple cities and then process it in Airflow. Currently, I'm fetching forecast data for Moscow, Kazan, Saint Petersburg, Tula, and Novosibirsk for the next 7 days. However, I've noticed that the process of fetching and transforming this data is taking longer than expected.
Here's what I'm currently doing:
Retrieving forecast data for each city using the Yandex Weather API.
Parsing the JSON response to extract the necessary fields such as temperature, pressure, and precipitation.
Transforming the data into a CSV format.
Uploading the CSV file to a cloud storage solution.
However, this process seems to be time-consuming, especially when dealing with a large volume of data.
Additional Information:
The Yandex Weather API documentation can be found here.
I'm particularly interested in optimizing the data retrieval and transformation steps to reduce the overall processing time.
Are there any strategies or techniques that can be employed to speed up the retrieval of data from the API?
Additionally, are there any optimizations that can be made during the data transformation process to improve efficiency?
Can these optimization techniques be integrated into an Airflow workflow to streamline the entire process?
Any insights or suggestions on how to improve the efficiency of this data retrieval and transformation process would be greatly appreciated.
